# How evaluate external command to a Nix value?

Tags: nix

I want to parse a file to a Nix list value inside `flake.nix`.
I have a shell script which does that

```
perl -007 -nE 'say for m{[(]use-package \s* ([a-z-0-9]+) \s* (?!:nodep)}xsgm' init.el
```

How can I execute external command while evaluating `flake.nix`?

```
    programs.emacs = {
      enable = true;
      extraConfig = builtins.readFile ./init.el;
      extraPackages = elpa: (shellCommandToParseFile ./init.el); # Runs shell script
   };
```

Comment: If you want to use Nix code that's generated this way, you have to do something called "import from derivation". You might want to read up on the reasons people are trying to transition away from the practice before writing more code that uses it.

Comment: BTW, how do you get a valid shebang for `init.el`? If it's elisp, I assume you're running it with emacs? Can you provide a command line for that I can use in my answer? (It's been a lot of years since emacs was my daily driver).

Comment: ...it's a _perl_ script? Why the .el extension on a perl script? But I'm very glad to see it doesn't do any network access; that makes things a lot easier.

Comment: BTW, it'd be helpful for me to see an example of what the output of your perl is, to understand if it's actually nix code that can be `import`ed or something else; now that I see what code you _have_ provided, I'm not sure that I understood the larger context for exactly _how_ you want to transform its output into `extraPackages`. (If you just want to split its text into strings and search for each string in `pkgs`, for example, that's a thing that's different and doesn't require any import).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `./init.el` by the same way you perform any other impure step in Nix: With a derivation.

This might look something vaguely like:

```
   programs.emacs = {
      enable = true;
      extraConfig = ../init.el;
      extraPackages = elpa:
        let
          packageListNix =
            pkgs.runCommand "init-packages.nix" { input = ../init.el; } ''
              ${pkgs.perl}/bin/perl  -007 -nE '
              BEGIN {
                  say "{elpa, ...}: with elpa; [";
                  say "use-package";
              };
              END   { say "]" };
              while (m{[(]use-package \s* ([a-z-0-9]+) \s* (;\S+)?}xsgm) {
                 next if $2 eq ";builtin";
                 say $1;
              }' "$input" >"$out"
            '';
        in (import "${packageListNix}" { inherit elpa; });
    };
```

...assuming that, given the contents of your `./init.el`, the contents of your resulting `el-pkgs.nix` *is actually valid nix source code*.

That said, note that like any other derivation (that isn't either fixed-output or explicitly impure), this happens inside a sandbox with no network access. If the goal of `init.el` is to connect to a network resource, you should be committing its output to your repository. A major design goal of flakes is to *remove* impurities; they're not suitable for impure derivations.